# Cloudflare SSL Does Not Work With Elixir/Phoenix Backend

Tags: ssl, networking, elixir, phoenix-framework, cloudflare

I am using Cloudflare's flexible SSL to secure my website, and it works fine when running my vue.js frontend. Essentially what it is doing is sharing the SSL cert with 50 random customers, and it does so by piping my DNS through their edge network. Basically, it did the thing I needed and was fine, but now that I am trying to tie it to a phoenix/elixir backend it is breaking.

The problem is that you can't make an http request from inside an ssl page, because you'll get this error:

`Blocked loading mixed active content`

This makes sense - if it's ssl on load, it needs to be ssl all the way down. So now I need to add SSL to elixir.

This site (https://elixirforum.com/t/run-phoenix-https-behind-cloudflare-without-key-keyfile/12660/2) seemed to have the solution! Their answer was:

```
configs = Keyword.put(config, :http, [:inet6, port: "80"])
 |> Keyword.put(:url, [scheme: "https", host: hostname, port: "443"])
```

So I made my config like this:

```
config :albatross, AlbatrossWeb.Endpoint,
  http: [:inet6, port: "4000"],
  url: [scheme: "https", host: "my.website", port: "443"],
  secret_key_base: "SUPERSECRET",
  render_errors: [view: AlbatrossWeb.ErrorView, accepts: ~w(html json)],
  pubsub: [name: Albatross.PubSub,
           adapter: Phoenix.PubSub.PG2]
```

That only allows me to get to http:etc! So I've also tried this:

```
config :albatross, AlbatrossWeb.Endpoint,
  http: [:inet6, port: "4000"],
  https: [ :inet6, port: "4443"],
  url: [scheme: "https", host: "my.website", port: "443"],
  secret_key_base: "SUPERSECRET",
  render_errors: [view: AlbatrossWeb.ErrorView, accepts: ~w(html json)],
  pubsub: [name: Albatross.PubSub,
           adapter: Phoenix.PubSub.PG2]
```

Which doesn't work of course because there's no PEM files. Since I'm only using elixir as an API (and not a DNS) I can't use solutions like this (http://51percent.tech/blog/uncategorized/serving-phoenix-apps-ssl-and-lets-encrypt/), because letsencrypt does not allow IP address only auth (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/ssl-for-ip-address).

So at this point I'm very confused. Does anyone have any advice?

---

**EDIT:**

---

Someone mentioned that you can go on to cloudflare and generate TLS certs by going to `crypto>Origin Certificates>Create Certificate`. I did that, downloaded the files, saved them in my project and ran this:

```
config :albatross, AlbatrossWeb.Endpoint,
  http: [:inet6, port: "4000"],
  https: [ port: "4443", 
           keyfile: "priv/ssl/cloudflare/private.key", 
           certfile: "priv/ssl/cloudflare/public.pem"],
  url: [scheme: "https", host: "website.me", port: "443"],
  secret_key_base: "SUPERSECRET",
  render_errors: [view: AlbatrossWeb.ErrorView, accepts: ~w(html json)],
  pubsub: [name: Albatross.PubSub,
           adapter: Phoenix.PubSub.PG2]
```

So what are the results of all the possible ways to query the backend?

Well I'm running docker-compose so `https://backendservice:4443` is what I query from the frontend. That gives me -

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://backendservice:4443/getComments?postnum=6. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).[Learn More]
value of error :  Error: "Network Error"
    exports https://mywebsi.te/js/chunk-vendors.4345f11a.js:49:15423
    onerror https://mywebsi.te/js/chunk-vendors.4345f11a.js:65:538540
actions.js:61:12
```

So that clearly doesn't work.

I *can* go to `http://my.ip.address:4000`, but I *cannot* go to `https://my.ip.address:4443`.

**As far as I can tell cloudflare TLS certificates do not work.**

*Or, more likely, I am doing something stupid in writing the elixir config.*

---

**FURTHER CLARIFICATION:**

---

Yes, there is a CORS header error above. *However* please note that it is *only* firing for https request and NOT http requests. Why this is happening is very confusing. I have a cors plugin for elixir in the entrypoint of my application that is currently allowing * incoming requests. This is it - it should be pretty straight forward:

`plug CORSPlug, origin: "*"`

More information can be found here (https://github.com/mschae/cors_plug).

Comment: I could be wrong, but in a setup like this doesn't cloudflare terminate SSL on their end and just send you an HTTP request? Which means you wouldn't need to setup anything within Phoenix. You probably just need to make sure your frontend is sending an HTTPS request instead of an HTTP request?

Comment: No, that's not correct. If I don't do anything special my backend resolves at http://MY.IP.ADDRESS/route. If I https request there is nothing there, and if I http request I get the `Blocked loading mixed active content` error.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have been able to make my website work with the following configuration:

```
config :my_app, MyAppWeb.Endpoint,
  force_ssl: [hsts: true],
  url: [host: "my.website", port: 443],
  http: [:inet6, port: 4000],
  https: [
    :inet6,
    port: 8443,
    cipher_suite: :strong,
    keyfile: "private.key.pem",
    certfile: "public.cert.pem",
    cacertfile: "intermediate.cert.pem"
  ],
  cache_static_manifest: "priv/static/cache_manifest.json"
```

where `private.key.pem` and `public.cert.pem` are the origin certificate downloaded from Cloudflare.

(Note that the origin certificate you can download from Cloudflare is only useful for encrypting the connection between your website and Cloudflare.)

I also had to add routing rules via `iptables`.

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 4000
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443
```

This configuration also worked before for a setup using *letsencrypt* certificates.

I'm not sure if the `cacertfile: "intermediate.cert.pem"` part is needed. I obtained it from "Step 4" of the [Cloudflare documentation](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000479507).

Answer (score 0):

I never used Cloudflare but I know that phoenix can pretend it is serving https content if `x-forwarded-proto` is set in request headers. Your configuration is OK (without https part, you don't need it).

Try to add `force_ssl` option in endpoint configuration. This will instruct to Plug.SSL to force SSL and redirect any http request to https.

```
config :albatross, AlbatrossWeb.Endpoint,
   http: [:inet6, port: "4000"],
   url: [scheme: "https", host: "my.website", port: "443"],
   force_ssl: [rewrite_on: [:x_forwarded_proto], host: nil],
   secret_key_base: "SUPERSECRET",
   render_errors: [view: AlbatrossWeb.ErrorView, accepts: ~w(html json)],
   pubsub: [name: Albatross.PubSub,
           adapter: Phoenix.PubSub.PG2]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with Cloudflare and web backends (and without seeing the *exact* request that is causing the issue), this is usually caused by hard-coding a CSS/JS dependency with `http://` or by making an AJAX request with `http://` hard-coded. If the back end you are requesting with `http://` doesn't automatically redirect to `https://`, you will get the error you're seeing.

If you're using Cloudflare's "One-Click SSL", this is how requests are being made to your server:

```
[ Client Browser ] <-- HTTPS --> [ Cloudflare ] <-- HTTP --> [ Your Server ]
```

Since the communication between Cloudflare and your server is all over `http://`, you should not need to change any Phoenix configuration at all, **but** there are 2 potential sources of error:

1. Automatic redirection to `https://` is not being done by Cloudflare (or Cloudflare is not serving your content)
2. You have some CSS/JS dependencies or Ajax requests that are hard-coded to `http://` and the server responding to the requests is not automatically redirecting to `https://`.

**Troubleshooting point 1**: According to [Cloudflare's docs for their "One-Click SSL"](https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/), they should automatically redirect `http://` requests to `https://` (although this might be a setting that you need to change). If a request comes to your domain over `http://`, Cloudflare should automatically redirect to `https://`. You can check whether this is happening by requesting a page from your backend in your browser with `http://` **explicitly** included at the front of the URL. If you are not redirected to `https://`, it could mean that a) Cloudflare is not actually in between your browser and the backend or b) that Cloudflare is not automatically redirecting to `https://`. In either case, you have some hints about your next step in solving the problem.

**Troubleshooting point 2:** You can check this by using the "Network" tab in the developer tools in your browser, or by manually going through your website code looking for CSS/JS dependencies or Ajax requests hard-coded with `http://`. In the developer tools, you can check for exactly which request(s) are causing the problem (the line should be red and have an error about mixed content). From there you can check where this request is coming from in your code. When searching through your code for hard-coded `http://` requests, most of the time you can simply replace it with `https://` directly, but you should double-check the URL in your browser to make sure that the URL is actually available over `https://`. If the CSS/JS dependency or Ajax endpoint is not actually available over `https://` then you will need to remove/replace it.

Hope this helps.